# How to configure multiple tracking code of Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I have created two accounts (`www.websiteUrl1.com and www.websiteUrl2.com`) in my Google Analytics account. 
Actually `www.websiteUrl1.com` and `www.websiteUrl2.com` shares the same code base and deployed on single server and single portal. 
Now we want to track traffic of `www.websiteUrl1.com` and `www.websiteUrl2.com` separately. Each this account has their own tracking code and not sure how can we add another tracking code there.

This is how we have configured tracking code in our website as

```
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics. www.websiteUrl1.com -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXXX-1');
</script>
```

Can you please guide how can we configure another urls (`www.websiteUrl2.com`) tracking code?

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you are asking.   If you want to track the same page to do different tracking ids your going to have to have the snippet twice.

Comment: @DaImTo. I have added a snippet twice but when I see the data on google analytics dhashboard I can see the request made on websiteUrl2 is also captured in websiteUrl1. Ex If I access  www.websiteUrl2.com/About it should come on analytics of websiteUrl2 only as /About however this is visible on websiteUrl1's analytics dashboard as well. My assumption is if I am making a request for websiteUrl2 it should not be captured for websiteUrl1.

Comment: Thats becouse you have the snippet there twice your writing the data to both Google analytics accounts.  If you only want it in one google analytics account you should only have one snippet per site like normal.   Again im not sure i understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch the analytics code server side based on the referring domain. If the domain is [www.websiteUrl1.com](http://www.websiteUrl1.com) write out tracking code 1, if it is [www.websiteUrl2.com](http://www.websiteUrl2.com) write out tracking code 2.